# Can I award a bounty on an already-accepted answer?

Tags: support, bounty

A few days ago, I asked a question and quickly received an answer...

[What setting will convince Windows menus to appear to the right, instead of left?](https://superuser.com/q/346753/31438)

Because the answer was received quickly, I never got the chance to offer a bounty - but I'd still like to award a small bounty. OK, I don't need to promote the question because I already got the answer, but I'd still like to reward the guy for saving my sanity.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait 2 days or so for the bounty option to become available. There should be a tiny message below your question stating when this option will be available.

Here's where the message appears for one of my questions:

> [image]

At the same location, the message telling you when your question is old enough should also be visible.

---

As the bounty is offered quite publicly, you should add a comment to your question stating that it's not about attracting additional answers, but to reward the user that posted the answer already.

Comment: I've tried the unaccept-and-reload and there's still no message - there was one when I asked the question yesterday, but not now. Do I leave the answer unaccepted for a while to see what happens, or ???

Comment: @Steve314 You asked the question 45hrs ago. You can offer a bounty after 48hrs. That might be the issue. Wait ~3hrs, then the link should appear.

Comment: @slhck There should be a message indicating when that option will become available. I remember seeing that for a question I recently asked.

Comment: Interesting. Stack Overflow shows "you can offer a bounty in x days/x hours" right from the time you posted the question

Comment: @Sathya Wouldn't make sense to wait as it's only 2 days, and interest in getting a solution is probably greatest when posted. This probably helps in reducing "I want to set a bounty because I need to know NOW!" flags and Meta posts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Just wait till the two days are over and a *start a bounty* link will appear under the question.

An accept mark does not have an effect on the abilitiy to give a bounty...

Comment: Confirmed by checking an older already-accepted answer - thanks.